# Могу ли я хранить все конопки, виджеты и текстреи в отдельном файле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyside2

У меня в шаблоне есть повторяющиеся куски кода. Чтобы оптимизировать код, я хочу разделить шаблон на несколько частей и загружать в зависимости от того, что запрашивает пользователь.

Например я хочу вставить кнопки `#but_1`, `#but_1`, `#but_2`, `#but_1` из `test2` во внутрь `#smile_window_tes`. слева от `#label`

**test1.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_Windows_main(object):
    def setupUi(self, Windows_main):
        if Windows_main.objectName():
            Windows_main.setObjectName(u"Windows_main")
        Windows_main.resize(764, 604)
        Windows_main.setStyleSheet(u"\n"
"\n"
"#Test_window #Window_test{\n"
"background-color: rgb(239, 41, 41);\n"
"}
"#Test_window #smile_window_tes{\n"
"background-color: #fff;\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.Test_window = QWidget(Windows_main)
        self.Test_window.setObjectName(u"Test_window")
        self.Test_window.setEnabled(True)
        self.Test_window.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.Test_window)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 142, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.horizontalSpacer = QSpacerItem(254, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.horizontalSpacer, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.Window_test = QWidget(self.Test_window)
        self.Window_test.setObjectName(u"Window_test")
        self.Window_test.setMinimumSize(QSize(250, 250))
        self.Window_test.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.Window_test)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.Text = QLabel(self.Window_test)
        self.Text.setObjectName(u"Text")
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(21)
        self.Text.setFont(font)
        self.Text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Text)

        self.smile_window_tes = QWidget(self.Window_test)
        self.smile_window_tes.setObjectName(u"smile_window_tes")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(self.smile_window_tes)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QLabel(self.smile_window_tes)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")

        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.smile_window_tes)

        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(1, 1)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Window_test, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.verticalSpacer_2 = QSpacerItem(20, 141, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.horizontalSpacer_2 = QSpacerItem(254, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.horizontalSpacer_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        Windows_main.setCentralWidget(self.Test_window)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(Windows_main)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 764, 22))
        Windows_main.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(Windows_main)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        Windows_main.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Windows_main)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Windows_main)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Windows_main):
        Windows_main.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Windows_main", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.Text.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Windows_main", u"Text", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Windows_main", u"TextLabel", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

**test2.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_array_but(object):
    def setupUi(self, array_but):
        if array_but.objectName():
            array_but.setObjectName(u"array_but")
        array_but.resize(800, 583)
        array_but.setStyleSheet(u"#but_1{\n"
"background:rgb(243, 255, 11)\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"#but_2{\n"
"background:rgb(56, 255, 239)\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(array_but)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.but_1 = QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.but_1.setObjectName(u"but_1")
        self.but_1.setGeometry(QRect(0, 10, 83, 18))
        self.but_2 = QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.but_2.setObjectName(u"but_2")
        self.but_2.setGeometry(QRect(0, 40, 83, 18))
        array_but.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(array_but)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        array_but.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(array_but)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        array_but.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(array_but)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(array_but)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, array_but):
        array_but.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("array_but", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.but_1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("array_but", u"But 1", None))
        self.but_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("array_but", u"But 2", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

**main.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter, QPixmap,
    QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget
import sys


from test1 import Ui_Windows_main
from test2 import Ui_array_but

class QtMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Windows_main):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    my = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtMainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(my.exec_())
```

Как это сделать и вызовет ли это какие либо ошибки или конфликты имен?
Я только начал изучать pyside поэтому и спрашиваю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете делать все в пределах разумного. Я бы сделал это так:

1. Создал класс `Qt_array_but` закачал туда `Ui_array_but`
2. Подключил его в классе `QtMainWindow`

   `self.array_but = Qt_array_but(self)`

Все, берите из него атрибуты какие вам надо и делайте с ними что-нибудь.

---

Обратите внимание, что вам надо будет поменять импорты, т.к. у меня `PyQt5`

Еще одно изменение, которое я внес - это строка

```
self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

т.к. вы захотели вставит слева от #label

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import  *


# from test2 import Ui_array_but
class Ui_array_but(object):
    def setupUi(self, array_but):
        if array_but.objectName():
            array_but.setObjectName(u"array_but")
        array_but.resize(800, 583)
        array_but.setStyleSheet(u"#but_1{\n"
"background:rgb(243, 255, 11)\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"#but_2{\n"
"background:rgb(56, 255, 239)\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(array_but)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.but_1 = QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.but_1.setObjectName(u"but_1")
        self.but_1.setGeometry(QRect(0, 10, 83, 18))
        self.but_2 = QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.but_2.setObjectName(u"but_2")
        self.but_2.setGeometry(QRect(0, 40, 83, 18))
        array_but.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(array_but)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        array_but.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(array_but)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        array_but.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(array_but)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(array_but)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, array_but):
        array_but.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("array_but", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.but_1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("array_but", u"But 1", None))
        self.but_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("array_but", u"But 2", None))
    # retranslateUi
    

# from test1 import Ui_Windows_main    
class Ui_Windows_main(object):
    def setupUi(self, Windows_main):
        if Windows_main.objectName():
            Windows_main.setObjectName(u"Windows_main")
        Windows_main.resize(764, 604)
        Windows_main.setStyleSheet("""
            #Test_window #Window_test{
                background-color: rgb(239, 41, 41);
            }
            #Test_window #smile_window_tes{
                background-color: #fff;
            }
        """)
        self.Test_window = QWidget(Windows_main)
        self.Test_window.setObjectName(u"Test_window")
        self.Test_window.setEnabled(True)
        self.Test_window.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.Test_window)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 142, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.horizontalSpacer = QSpacerItem(254, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.horizontalSpacer, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.Window_test = QWidget(self.Test_window)
        self.Window_test.setObjectName(u"Window_test")
        self.Window_test.setMinimumSize(QSize(250, 250))
        self.Window_test.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.Window_test)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.Text = QLabel(self.Window_test)
        self.Text.setObjectName(u"Text")
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(21)
        self.Text.setFont(font)
        self.Text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Text)

        self.smile_window_tes = QWidget(self.Window_test)
        self.smile_window_tes.setObjectName(u"smile_window_tes")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(self.smile_window_tes)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QLabel(self.smile_window_tes)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")

        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)                    # 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.smile_window_tes)
        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Window_test, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalSpacer_2 = QSpacerItem(20, 141, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalSpacer_2 = QSpacerItem(254, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.horizontalSpacer_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        Windows_main.setCentralWidget(self.Test_window)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(Windows_main)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 764, 22))
        Windows_main.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(Windows_main)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        Windows_main.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Windows_main)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Windows_main)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Windows_main):
        Windows_main.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Windows_main", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.Text.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Windows_main", u"Text", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Windows_main", u"TextLabel", None))
    # retranslateUi
    

class Qt_array_but(QMainWindow, Ui_array_but):                                  # +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Qt_array_but, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        

class QtMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Windows_main):   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.array_but = Qt_array_but(self)                                      # +++
        
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.array_but.but_1, 0, 0, 1, 1,            # +++  
                                    alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.array_but.but_2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 
                                    alignment=Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignTop)      # +++
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> А разве у `but_1` не должен быть желтый фон, а у `but_2` голубой?
>
> И можно ли использовать несколько раз одну и туже кнопку, например вставить три раза кнопку but_1 и что бы на них распространялась одинаковая логика.

1. Фон добавил, смотрите `app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)`
2. Все объекты уникальны используйте из где вам надо, но вставить три раза кнопку but_1 - НЕ ПОЛУЧИТСЯ, вы ее увидите только в последнем, третьем месте. Вы ведь можете это проверить.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import  *



class Ui_array_but(object):
    def setupUi(self, array_but):
        if array_but.objectName():
            array_but.setObjectName(u"array_but")
        array_but.resize(800, 583)
        array_but.setStyleSheet(u"#but_1{\n"
"background:rgb(243, 255, 11)\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"#but_2{\n"
"background:rgb(56, 255, 239)\n"
"}")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(array_but)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.but_1 = QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.but_1.setObjectName(u"but_1")
        self.but_1.setGeometry(QRect(0, 10, 83, 18))
        self.but_2 = QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.but_2.setObjectName(u"but_2")
        self.but_2.setGeometry(QRect(0, 40, 83, 18))
        array_but.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(array_but)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        array_but.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(array_but)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        array_but.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(array_but)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(array_but)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, array_but):
        array_but.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("array_but", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.but_1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("array_but", u"But 1", None))
        self.but_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("array_but", u"But 2", None))
    # retranslateUi
    

# from test1 import Ui_Windows_main    
class Ui_Windows_main(object):
    def setupUi(self, Windows_main):
        if Windows_main.objectName():
            Windows_main.setObjectName(u"Windows_main")
        Windows_main.resize(764, 604)
        Windows_main.setStyleSheet("""
            #Test_window #Window_test{
                background-color: rgb(239, 41, 41);
            }
            #Test_window #smile_window_tes{
                background-color: #fff;
            }
        """)
        self.Test_window = QWidget(Windows_main)
        self.Test_window.setObjectName(u"Test_window")
        self.Test_window.setEnabled(True)
        self.Test_window.setTabletTracking(False)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.Test_window)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 142, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.horizontalSpacer = QSpacerItem(254, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.horizontalSpacer, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.Window_test = QWidget(self.Test_window)
        self.Window_test.setObjectName(u"Window_test")
        self.Window_test.setMinimumSize(QSize(250, 250))
        self.Window_test.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.Window_test)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.Text = QLabel(self.Window_test)
        self.Text.setObjectName(u"Text")
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(21)
        self.Text.setFont(font)
        self.Text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Text)

        self.smile_window_tes = QWidget(self.Window_test)
        self.smile_window_tes.setObjectName(u"smile_window_tes")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QGridLayout(self.smile_window_tes)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_2")
        self.label = QLabel(self.smile_window_tes)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")

        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)                    # 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.smile_window_tes)
        self.verticalLayout.setStretch(1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Window_test, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalSpacer_2 = QSpacerItem(20, 141, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalSpacer_2 = QSpacerItem(254, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(self.horizontalSpacer_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)
        Windows_main.setCentralWidget(self.Test_window)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(Windows_main)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 764, 22))
        Windows_main.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(Windows_main)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        Windows_main.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Windows_main)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Windows_main)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Windows_main):
        Windows_main.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Windows_main", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.Text.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Windows_main", u"Text", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Windows_main", u"TextLabel", None))
    # retranslateUi
    

class Qt_array_but(QMainWindow, Ui_array_but):                                  # +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Qt_array_but, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        

class QtMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_Windows_main):   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.array_but = Qt_array_but()                                         # +++ self
        
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.array_but.but_1, 0, 0, 1, 1,            # +++  
                                    alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.array_but.but_2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 
                                    alignment=Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignTop)      # +++
        


# vvvvvvvv StyleSheet +++
StyleSheet = """
#but_1{
    background:rgb(243, 255, 11);
}
#but_2{
    background:rgb(56, 255, 239);
}
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)                    # <----- StyleSheet
    
    window = QtMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А разве у but_1 не должен быть желтый фон, а у but_2 голубой? И можно ли использовать несколько раз одну и туже кнопку например вставить три раза кнопку but_1 и что бы на них распростронялась одинаковая логика. `def bp():
 window.textEdit.setText('lol')
 
window.but_1.clicked.connect(bp)`

Comment: @orlatym я добавил `update`

Comment: @orlatym скажите пожалуйста мой ответ (с обновлениями), решил вашу проблему ?